# How to detect changes to the BindableObjects from the View?

Tags: swiftui

In UIKit, I would have code like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemNameField: UITextField!
@IBAction func itemNameFieldDone(_ sender: UITextField) {
    thisItem.myName = sender.text ?? thisItem.myName
    thisItem.modified()
}
```

In the model object:

```
func modified() {
    dateModified = Date()
    let cds = FoodyDataStack.thisDataStack
    uuidUser = cds.uuidUser
    uuidFamily = cds.uuidFamily
}
```

In SwiftUI:

```
TextField($thisItem.myName)
```

Declarative, nice and short. SwiftUI takes care of updating the `myName` property as the user types in the TextField, but how do I get the `dateModified` property to update at the same time?

Comment: Maybe put a setter in the model? https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID260

Comment: Error `@NSManaged not allowed on observing properties`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `TextField` initializer that includes `onEditingChanged` and include whatever updating code you need in the closure.

```
TextField($thisCategory.myName, placeholder: nil, onEditingChanged: { (changed) in
                    self.thisCategory.modified()
                    self.dataStack.didChange.send(self.dataStack)
                }).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
```

Answer (score 0):

## iOS 14

There is a new modifier called `onChange` to detect changes of any state:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $text)
            .onChange(of: text, perform: { value in
                print(text)
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `didSet` observer to `myName` property in your item type declaration and then call `modified` from there:

```
var myName: String = "" {
            didSet {
                self.modified()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Error @NSManaged no allowed on observing properties.